# How to move the last digit to the first position of a number in cobol

Tags: cobol

Say I have the number 123456, how can i move the 6 to the beginning so it becomes 612345?

needs to work if the number has fewer digits like 123 becoming 312.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome here. Please recheck the tour to see what questions to ask and how to write questions that show what you've tried so far next time. Thank you.

Comment: Will do, my apologies Simon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general purpose method that will work with any integer from 2 to 32 digits. The number must be `usage display`.

```
   working-storage section.
   1 a-number pic 9(6) value 123456.
   1 b-number pic 9(3) value 123.
   1 work pic x(32).
   1 len-of-number binary pic 9(4).
   procedure division.
   begin.
       display a-number
       move a-number (1:) to work
       perform swap-digit
       move work to a-number (1:)
       display a-number
       display space
       display b-number
       move b-number (1:) to work
       perform swap-digit
       move work to b-number (1:)
       display b-number
       stop run
       .
   swap-digit.
       move 0 to len-of-number
       inspect work tallying
           len-of-number for characters before space
       move function reverse (work (1:len-of-number))
           to work
       move function reverse (work (2:len-of-number - 1))
           to work (2:len-of-number - 1)
       .
```

Output:

```
123456
612345

123
312
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution. Just `MOVE` your input to the `VAR-INPUT`. It is a alphanumeric picture clause, but it doesn't matter because you want a string as output.

Also I chose random picture clause lengths, you can choose whatever length you want.

```
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

           01  VAR-INPUT    PIC X(20).
           01  VAR1         PIC X(10).
           01  VAR2         PIC X(10).
           01  RESULT       PIC X(20).
           01  L            PIC 9(02).
           01  OFFSET       PIC 9(02).

 PROCEDURE DIVISION.

               COMPUTE L      = LENGTH OF VAR-INPUT
               COMPUTE OFFSET = L - 1

               MOVE VAR-INPUT(1:L)      TO VAR1
               MOVE VAR-INPUT(OFFSET:1) TO VAR2

               STRING VAR1 DELIMITED BY SPACE
                      VAR2 DELIMITED BY SPACE
               INTO   RESULT
```

Comment: This needs more details, what are the picture clauses, also the line will cause a syntax error in most compilers

Comment: I will write the full working program in a bit, test it and edit my answer :)

Comment: This will not work VAR1 and VAR2 are both PIC X(10) so when you string them together delimited by size you will get 6 then 9 spaces 12345 as opposed to 612345

Comment: I'll have to use DELIMITED BY SPACE. Or make the VAR1 a PIC X(01) assuming he always wants the last digit (and not multiple)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example from OpenCobolIDE

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 A PIC X(37).
    01 B PIC 9(2).
    01 C PIC X(1).
    01 D PIC 9(2).
    01 E PIC 9(2).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      ACCEPT A.
      INSPECT A TALLYING B FOR CHARACTERS BEFORE SPACE.
      MOVE A(B:) TO C.

      PERFORM VARYING D FROM B BY -1 UNTIL D = 1
         MOVE D TO E
         SUBTRACT 1 FROM E
         MOVE A(E:1) TO A(D:1) 
      END-PERFORM.

      MOVE C TO A(1:1).
      DISPLAY A.
   END PROGRAM YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
```

Insert a DISPLAY A inside the PERFORM loop to see how the workflow goes.

Comment: This solution worked, but i dont understand where you specify the number to be transformed. could you kindly clarify?

Comment: @JoãoMateus There is no number specified, but "whatever data" entered  by the operator with the simplest format of the [`ACCEPT` statement](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/wiki/verbs.accept/).

Comment: Yes. You could omit the ACCEPT A and instead move the data to A before having the code perform (preferably in a separate method).